# Spring CXF Conduit SSL Client pointing at Soap UI Mock Service

Tags: spring, web-services, ssl, cxf, soapui

I am currently working on a Web Service client which will connect to a third party web service  using SSL.

The Web Service client has been developed using Spring and Apache CXF.

I do not have access to the third party web service at the moment and so I am using Soap UI to provide Mock Services.

When I do not attempt to implement any security the client can happily send requests to the Mock Service.

My issue is when I try and secure the connection between the client and server(the server being the mock service) using SSL.

This is the first time I have tried to implement a secure connection of any kind so I apologise if I am missing something fundamental however I have spent hours searching around the subject to no avail.

In order to attempt to secure the connection I have created a private key, self-signed certificate and truststore for both the client and the server using the Java keytool utility:

```
keytool -genkey -alias clientKey -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore clientKeyStore.jks

keytool -export -alias clientKey -storepass changeit -file client.cer -keystore clientKeyStore.jks

keytool -genkey -alias serverKey -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore serverKeyStore.jks

keytool -export -alias serverKey -storepass changeit -file server.cer -keystore serverKeyStore.jks
```

I have added the certificates from both keys to both of the trust stores:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias clientKey -file client.cer -keystore serverCaCerts.jks -keypass changeit

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias clientKey -file client.cer -keystore clientCaCerts.jks -keypass changeit

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias serverKey -file server.cer -keystore serverCaCerts.jks -keypass changeit

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias serverKey -file server.cer -keystore clientCaCerts.jks -keypass changeit
```

I have then configured the Mock Services in Soap UI to use SSL security

```
KeyStore: C:\javaSecurity\serverKeyStore.jks
KeyStore Password: changeit
Enable Mock SSL: True (enable SSL for Mock Services)
Mock Port: 8443
Mock KeyStore: C:\javaSecurity\serverKeyStore.jks
Mock Password: changeit
Mock Key Password: changeit
Mock TrustStore: C:\javaSecurity\serverCaCerts.jks
Mock TrustStore Password: changeit
Client Authentication: false(does not require client authentication)
```

I have then set up the following config in my applicationContext.xml of the client:

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters secureSocketProtocol="SSL" disableCNCheck="true">
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit"
                          file="C:\\javaSecurity\\clientKeyStore.jks"/>
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit"
                          file="C:\\javaSecurity\\clientCaCerts.jks"/>
        </sec:trustManagers>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>

    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>
</http:conduit>
```

When I attempt to send a message from the client I get the following error from the client:

```
2014-01-28 14:17:36,094 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,098 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,099 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,099 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,099 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,099 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,099 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,100 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,100 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,100 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,100 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,101 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,101 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,101 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,101 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,102 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,102 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,102 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,103 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,104 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,104 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,104 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,104 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The enabled cipher suites have been filtered down to [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5].
2014-01-28 14:17:36,105 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The excluded cipher suites have been filtered down to [SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA].  
2014-01-28 14:17:36,107 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (LogUtils.java:443) - The cipher suites have been set to SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5.  
2014-01-28 14:17:36,107 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (Headers.java:257) - Accept: */*
2014-01-28 14:17:36,107 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (HTTPConduit.java:1707) - No Trust Decider for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'. An afirmative Trust Decision is assumed.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,247 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (DefaultResourceManager.java:103) - resolving resource <https://pc-1049:8443/mockServiceSOAPBinding?WSDL> as stream 
2014-01-28 14:17:36,248 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (DefaultResourceManager.java:103) - resolving resource <https://pc-1049:8443/mockServiceSOAPBinding?WSDL> type <class java.net.URL>
2014-01-28 14:17:36,248 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (HTTPConduit.java:895) - Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit' has been (re)configured for plain http.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,249 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (HTTPConduit.java:361) - No Trust Decider configured for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'
2014-01-28 14:17:36,249 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (HTTPConduit.java:374) - No Auth Supplier configured for Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit'
2014-01-28 14:17:36,249 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (HTTPConduit.java:393) - Conduit '{http://cxf.apache.org}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit' has been configured for plain http.
2014-01-28 14:17:36,249 DEBUG [ServiceThread] (AbstractObservable.java:46) - registering incoming observer: org.apache.cxf.transport.TransportURIResolver$1@76e1db
```

In the SOAP UI log I get the following error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector$SslConnection.run(SslSocketConnector.java:708)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could anybody help me and point out what I may be missing?

As I mentioned earlier I do not have much experience in the area and so please do not think something is too fundamental to mention - if I've not mentioned it there is a good chance I've missed it!

Thankyou in advance to anyone who replies.

Comment: I have continued trying to progress with this and attempted to recreate the keys exactly as demonstrated in here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/src/main/config/KeyREADME.txt?view=log

And I am still getting the same behaviour - this is making me think that the issue is not with the keys but perhaps the conduit config?

The errors "No Trust Decider" and "No Auth Supplier" look like they could be caused by the applicationContext.xml not being paid attention to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this issue turned out to be where I was defining my http:conduit settings.

I had included the http-conduit definition in my applicationContext.xml

It in fact needed to be defined in a separate cxf.xml file located on the classpath.